# Using stack to check equal number of letters and digits in password

Tags: java, passwords, stack

I have to write a program to check a password whereby the password should

- should be at least 8 characters long
- contain only letters and digits(special characters)
- contain an equal number of letters and digits

The program should check if it is valid and displays an appropriate message.
Also, only the stack class should be used as the data structure.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
public class dsa_1c {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        String pass;

        System.out.println("Enter a password");
        pass= sc.nextLine();

        if(checkPass(pass)){
            System.out.println("Valid Password");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }
    }


        public static boolean checkPass(String password){

            Stack<Character> stack= new Stack<Character>();


            int count1=0, count2=0;

            if(password.length()<8){
                return false;
            }
            else{
             for(int i=0; i<password.length();i++){
                 char c= password.charAt(i);

                  if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){
                    return false;}

                  if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){

                    stack.push(c);

                  }

                    char top= stack.peek();

                  if(Character.isLetter(top)){
                      count1++;
                      stack.pop();                    

                  }

                  else if(Character.isDigit(top)){                  
                      count2++;
                      stack.pop();                    

                  }

                  if(count1==count2){
                 return true;
                  }

                  if(!stack.isEmpty()){
                 return false;
                  }

             }

            }
                return true;

            }

    }
```

The program when run displays "Valid Password" for any password I type in with more than 8 characters and with no special characters.
It's this part which is apparently the issue

```
if(count1==count2){
   return true;}
```

because when I change it

```
if(count1!=count2)
    return false; }
```

it returns Invalid Password for any valid ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `return true` in the end that causes an issue. Instead of comparing two counts and returning the values, you can just use `return count1 == count2;`. Below is an example:

```
public static boolean checkPass(String password) {

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    if (password.length() < 8) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            char c = password.charAt(i);

            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                stack.push(c);
            }
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            char c = stack.pop();
            if(Character.isLetter(c)){
                count1++;
            }else{
                count2++;
            }
        }
        return count1 == count2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for refining the code. Can you please explain how `return count1==count2;` did the boolean check? Didn't quite get that.

Comment: `count1==count2` returns a boolean, it's similar to `if(count1==count2){ return true;} else{return false;}`

Answer (score 1):

Using a stack seems like overkill to me - it's enough to iterate over the characters, count the digits and the letters, and make sure they have the same number:

```
private static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
    int letterCount = 0;
    int digitCount = ;
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); ++i) {
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            ++letterCount;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            ++digitCount;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (letterCount + digitCount) >= 8 &&
           letterCount == digitCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an exercise just to manipulate a stack, here is my 2 cents:

```
public class dsa_1c {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a password");
    String pass = sc.nextLine();

    if (checkPass(pass)) {
        System.out.println("Valid Password");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");
    }
}

private static boolean checkPass(String pass) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (pass.length() == 8) {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        for (char current : pass.toCharArray()) {
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                stack.push(current);
                continue;
            }
            char previousChar = stack.pop();
            if (sameType(current, previousChar)) {
                stack.push(previousChar);
                stack.push(current);
            }
        }
        if (stack.isEmpty()) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static boolean sameType(char current, char previousChar) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(current) && Character.isAlphabetic(previousChar)) {
        result = true;
    }
    else if (Character.isDigit(current) && Character.isDigit(previousChar)) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

static class Stack extends ArrayList {

    public static final char NULL_CHARACTER = 0x0;

    public void push(Character letter) {
        add(letter);
    }
    public Character pop() {
        Character result = NULL_CHARACTER;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            result = (Character)remove(size()-1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

}